# pytest: Fixture shortcut to object inside another fixture breaks when object is updated

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, pytest-fixtures

I have code that is essentially like this where the fixture `foo` is a shortcut to the `foo` object inside fixture `myclass`. This is purely for convenience so I don't have to do `myclass.foo`, however when `myclass.foo` gets updated, the `foo` fixture is not, even though they seem to be the same object before it's updated. Is this just a bad practice I should avoid?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = object()

    def update_foo(self):
        self.foo = object()

@pytest.fixture
def myclass():
    yield MyClass()

@pytest.fixture
def foo(myclass):
    return myclass.foo

def test_foo(myclass, foo):
    assert myclass.foo is foo
    myclass.update_foo()
    assert myclass.foo is foo  # <-- this one fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because immutability, a value cannot be changed after it has been created and every reference will point to the same value until you explicitly reassign the variable name.

it is not related to pytest but to python itself

you can read more about it [here](https://realpython.com/python-mutable-vs-immutable-types/#:%7E:text=An%20object%20that%20allows%20you,value%20is%20an%20immutable%20object.)

Answer (score 0):

This was (embarrassingly) an obfuscation of basic python assignment. `foo` is assigned the value of `myclass.foo`, it's not a reference to it. It's essentially the same as:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> z = y
>>> z is y
True
>>> y = 3
>>> z is y
False
```